# Apache camel from ftp to database

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is it possible to solve following scenario with apache camel:

Read from ftp (periodically) retrieve a zip file which contains xml, store this xml in database.

The main question is which features exists in camel and which functionality and need to write on my own?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your route could look something like this (off the top of my head):

```
JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat("com.example.foobar");

from("ftp://user:pass@server:21/inbox")
    .unmarshal().zip()
    .split(xpath("//foo"))
    .unmarshal(jaxb)
    .to("jpa:com.example.foobar.Foo")
```

This will poll a FTP server, unzip files, split the content in XML fragments, transform these to JPA entities and finally persist these objects in a database. There are many variations possible, depending on your use case you can omit the splitter EIP or for example choose another persistence mechanism (MyBatis, Spring-JDBC, etc).

Comment: In my case I need to save xml as CLOB in database, it will be an entity with a CLOB field and a couple of extra fields, what is not clear for me how I can get a body of the file after unzip and pass it inside jpa entity. I see a lot of data formats in org.apache.camel.model.dataformat but it seems to be used in other cases. Do I need to write my own data format to convert it to CLOB

Comment: As for now I want to convert xml to string and pass it to spring bean where it will store it to database via JdbcTemplate

Comment: Xml to Clob binding can probably be done during JAXB unmarshalling. Otherwise you can implement the message translator EIP (e.g. through a processor). As for the Xml->String->Spring bean way, just use: `.convertBodyTo(String.class).beanRef("fooBean","barMethod")`